# Waiting on many parallel shell commands with Perl

Tags: multithreading, perl, shell, cluster-computing

### Concise-ish problem explanation:

I'd like to be able to run multiple (we'll say a few hundred) shell commands, each of which starts a long running process and blocks for hours or days with at most a line or two of output (this command is simply a job submission to a cluster). This blocking is helpful so I can know exactly when each finishes, because I'd like to investigate each result and possibly re-run each multiple times in case they fail. My program will act as a sort of controller for these programs.

```
for all commands in parallel {
    submit_job_and_wait()
    tries = 1
    while ! job_was_successful and tries < 3{
        resubmit_with_extra_memory_and_wait()
        tries++
    }
}
```

### What I've tried/investigated:

I was so far thinking it would be best to create a thread for each submission which just blocks waiting for input. There is enough memory for quite a few waiting threads. But from what I've read, perl threads are closer to duplicate processes than in other languages, so creating hundreds of them is not feasible (nor does it feel right).

There also seem to be a variety of event-loop-ish cooperative systems like `AnyEvent` and `Coro`, but these seem to require you to rely on asynchronous libraries, otherwise you can't really do anything concurrently. I can't figure out how to make multiple shell commands with it. I've tried using `AnyEvent::Util::run_cmd`, but after I submit multiple commands, I have to specify the order in which I want to wait for them. I don't know in advance how long each submission will take, so I can't `recv` without sometimes getting very unlucky. This isn't really parallel.

```
my $cv1 = run_cmd("qsub -sync y 'sleep $RANDOM'");
my $cv2 = run_cmd("qsub -sync y 'sleep $RANDOM'");

# Now should I $cv1->recv first or $cv2->recv? Who knows!
# Out of 100 submissions, I may have to wait on the longest one before processing any.
```

My understanding of AnyEvent and friends may be wrong, so please correct me if so. :)

The other option is to run the job submission in its non-blocking form and have it communicate its completion back to my process, but the inter-process communication required to accomplish and coordinate this across different machines daunts me a little. I'm hoping to find a local solution before resorting to that.

Is there a solution I've overlooked?

Comment: What have you got against forking? What's "not feasible" of a couple of hundred? Are you running on an embedded system or some such?

Comment: I also don't have any understanding of `AnyEvent`, but shouldn't you just use `$cv->cb(sub { ... })` instead of `$cv->recv`?

Comment: @RichardHuxton: Well, 50788 kB / perl process(with e.g. Moose loaded) * 200 processes puts me at over 9 GB, so I'm hoping to avoid requesting a large memory node just to control other jobs. Unless I'm misunderstanding the memory behaviour?

Comment: Yes - if you fork a 50MB process, it'll share almost all of that and only allocate more when you write in the child. Give https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager a try and see how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

You could rather use Scientific Workflow software such as [fireworks](http://pythonhosted.org/FireWorks/) or [pegasus](http://pegasus.isi.edu/) which are designed to help scientists submit large numbers of computing jobs to shared or dedicated resources. But they can also do much more so it might be overkill for your problem, but they are still worth having a look at.

If your goal is to try and find the tightest memory requirements for you job, you could also simply submit your job with a large amount or requested memory, and then extract actual memory usage from accounting (`qacct`), or , cluster policy permitting, logging on the compute node(s) where your job is running and view the memory usage with `top` or `ps`.

Comment: Yeah, those look a little heavy, but thank you for the suggestion. I think I'm leaning toward just using a messaging library and turning it into a "distributed app" at this point.